# Parent's class static variable different value for child's classes

Tags: php, class, static

Please, sorry for my English.

My problem:

```
abstract class Entity
{
    protected static $fieldNames;

    public static function getFieldsNames()
    {
        if (is_null(static::$fieldNames)) {
            foreach (static::$fieldsMap as $name => $map) {
                static::$fieldNames[] = $name;
            }
        }

        return static::$fieldNames;
    }
}

class User extends Entity
{
    protected static $fieldsMap = [
        'id' => [
            // ...
        ],
        'name' => [
            // ...
        ],
        'phone' => [
            // ...
        ]
    ];
}

class Car extends Entity
{
    protected static $fieldsMap = [
        'id' => [
            // ...
        ],
        'brand' => [
            // ...
        ],
        'color' => [
            // ...
        ]
    ];
}

print_r(User::getFieldsNames());
// ['id', 'name', 'phone'] - On first call it works as expected, but...

print_r(Car::getFieldsNames());
// ['id', 'name', 'phone'] :(
```

If I declare $fieldNames in User and Car classes work fine, but in real project I has tens of static variables such $fieldNames and hundreds of entity's

Is it possible to best solution?

Maybe create small repository class that will keep these static variables by entity's id? or another elegant way?

Thanks any Help!

Comment: Probably because `$fieldNames` is static; and you're checking if it's already populated `if (is_null(static::$fieldNames)) {` so it won't repopulate for a different child class... why not simply `return static::$fieldsMap;`?

Comment: If you want to use static methods/variables in inheritence, then make sure that you use PHP7, because older versions had a lot of restrictions.

Comment: @Mark Baker
In real project will tens static variables with calculated/handled values, and I want set only one time these values for every entity while runtime script for better performance, for this reason, I can't use just 'return static::$var'

Comment: @Crouching Kitten
yes, php 7.0

Comment: Then don't build a one-time static map that then exists for all classes; or build an instance map... but I don't see how your real project variable values/quantities creates any problem with what I've suggested; you still have to define the individual $fieldsMap for each class entity

Comment: Alternatively, just define `protected static $fieldNames;` in each of the child classes; then the `getFieldsNames()` method from the parent will define it in the individual child classes, and not in itself

Answer (score 0):

$fieldNames is static so it's associated with the class itself and not with a specific object.
The class in this instance is "Entity".
Once you set it it is no longer null.